# display ul as dropdown

Tags: javascript, css, drop-down-menu, html-lists

Is it possible with pure css or really simple way to transfer nav ul menu as dropdown list when body width is smaller than given (media css) (mobile phones etc)

```
<nav>  
    <ul>  
        <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>  
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>  
        <li><a href="#">Archives</a></li>  
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>  
        <li class="subscribe"><a href="#">Subscribe via. RSS</a></li>  
    </ul>  
</nav>
```

Assuming: I want to display it normally, but when on mobile with narrow screen, want to display it as dropdown menu - same as select form.

[edit]

something like: http://themewich.com/aware/  -see the menu when resized.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you want exactly but this maybe can help you .I hope

```
<nav>  
<ul>  Test
    <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>  
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>  
    <li><a href="#">Archives</a></li>  
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>  
    <li class="subscribe"><a href="#">Subscribe via. RSS</a></li>  
</ul>  
</nav> ​

ul li{
  display:none;

}
 ul:hover li{
   display:block;

}​
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/afshinprofe/Mnkru/6/)

Answer (score 0):

You can detect the screen width using javascript, and if the screenwidth is too small, you can change the list to a dropdown menu using  tags. Google "javascript innerHTML" for more info how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the example URL with CSS disabled (or view the source), you will see that both types of navigation are present (nested list and form select).  The page is using media queries to determine which element to hide:  narrow devices will hide the list version while wide devices will hide the form version.